# JavaFX - tableview shows data but when saving to file, the file is empty

Tags: javafx, tableview, bufferedwriter

In my program I read a config file (.txt file) and show the content in a tableview. That works.

[Tableview with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XDGG.png)

The second column can be edited. This serves as a config file for the program.
If I now save the data (File - Save) the config file is empty. I have no idea, why. Here is the code:

File - Save calls this:

```
    @FXML
public void saveConfig() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("File - Save clicked");
    SCDConfigDataAccess configData = new SCDConfigDataAccess();
    configData.saveData(SCDController.configFile);
    closeConfig();
}//saveConfig
```

and configData.saveData does this:

```
public class SCDConfigDataAccess {
private static ObservableList<SCDConfigData> scdConfig;

    public void saveData(File configFile) throws IOException {
      BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(configFile.getPath()));
      String output = "";
      System.out.println("File: " + configFile.getPath());
      try { 
          for (SCDConfigData data : scdConfig) { 
              output = data.getsConfigType() + "=" + data.getsConfigValue() + "\n";
              System.out.println("Data: " + output);
              bw.write(output); } 
          bw.flush();
          bw.close();
      }catch(IOException e){ System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage()); }
} //saveData
}//class
```

I get these messages:
File - Save clicked
File: C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\SCD\scdconfig.ini

These are expected and correct.

I do not get a message out of the for-loop. That lets me think there is no data. But why? I see the data.

I'm sure I'm just missing a little thing. Any help is appreciated.
The config file was 127 bytes when I read it and is now 0.

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: [mcve] please .

Comment: I have created that example. How do I get it here? It is a maven project. Do I create a jar and attach it or what do I need to do? It's the first time I have a question, so please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was this line of code in the method saveConfig() of the controller

```
SCDConfigDataAccess configData = new SCDConfigDataAccess();
```

This creates a new instance and this does not have a connection to the data. Instead of doing this I use the instance defined in the controller class itself like so:

```
public class SCDConfigController {
private SCDConfigDataAccess configDataAccess;
    public void saveConfig() throws IOException {
    configDataAccess.saveData(SCDController.configFile);
    closeConfig();
}//saveConfig
```

And this of course works.